# How should I integrate this function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, special-functions, bessel-functions

Thank you for your precious time!

Here is the integration I want to calculate:

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{j 2 \pi\left[ \cos \theta- \cos \varphi+ \cos \left(\theta-\varphi\right)\right]} e^{j \theta} e^{-j \varphi} d \theta \, d \varphi$$

I think this integration is related to Bessel functions of the first kind, **when we remove the term $\cos(\theta-\varphi)$ above**:

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{j 2 \pi\left[ \cos \theta- \cos \varphi\right]} e^{j \theta} e^{-j \varphi}\, d \theta d \varphi=\int_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{j (2 \pi \cos \theta+\theta)} d\theta \int_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{-j (2 \pi \cos \varphi+\varphi)}\, d\varphi$$
With the bessel integration:
$$
J_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{j(n \tau-x \sin \tau)}\, d \tau
$$
The integration would be easy to get.

But due to the $\cos(\theta-\varphi)$ term in the desired integration, I still can't find a good method.

Could you give me any advice?

Any help would be appreciated!

-----------------------------------------2023/3/11------------------------------------------

According to @Semiclasical's suggestion, I tried:
$$e^{j c \cos \left(\theta-\varphi\right)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} j^{n} J_{n}\left(c\right) e^{i n\left(\theta-\varphi\right)}$$

So the integration would be:

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(c)j^n\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{j\left(a \cos \theta-b \cos \varphi\right)} e^{j\left(1+n\right) \theta} e^{-j\left(1+n\right) \varphi} d \theta d \varphi$$

And then it becomes:
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{4 \pi^{2}}{j^{-n}} J_{n}\left(c\right) J_{1+n}\left(a\right) J_{-\left(1+n\right)}\left(b\right)$$

I think this is useful. But the integration becomes the summation of series. To be more specific, the integration becomes the summation of Bessel functions. **It's still hard to get an analytical formula.**

I tried to truncate this series, but the accuracy severely degraded. So for now, I think I should try something else.
And currently, I'm planning to give Meijer-G function a try.

Could you give me more suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

-----------------------------------------2023/3/12------------------------------------------

I can't find useful Meijer-G functions for me.

But I find that the equation below is actually very accurate(even after truncation):
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{4 \pi^{2}}{j^{-n}} J_{n}\left(c\right) J_{1+n}\left(a\right) J_{-\left(1+n\right)}\left(b\right)$$

So I decide to stick on the sum of bessel functions. Since it's hard to get the bessel function summation directly. I used the asymptotic form of bessel functions:
$$
J_{\alpha}(z) \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{\alpha}
$$

Then we can transform bessel series into power series. The summation might be easier. This should work only when $z$ is very small since this asymptotic form of bessel function only works when $z$ is very small.

Could you give me any advice?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Along similar lines as you considered, the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi–Anger_expansion) may come in handy.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks! This gives me some inspiration. I will deliver an answer on this if possible.

Comment: What is $j$? Is $j$ a complex unit, if so which one, a real constant, a complex constant, or something else entirely?

Comment: @KevinDietrich Thanks for your reminding! For sure $j$ is a complex unit. Just like the $j$ in complex constant $a+bj$.